# Unable to get facedetection to work from sdcard android

Tags: android, face-detection

I am trying to use FaceDetection in android. 
If I decode the bitmap using the below line then the faces are detected -

```
Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face5,bitmapFatoryOptions);
```

However if I store the same image in the sdcard and try the use the below line, faces are not detected.

```
Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/axs" + "/face5.png");
```

I really dont know why this is happening. I am able to see the image on canvas in both the cases. However the first one highlights the detected faces, but not the second one. I guess there is some difference in the result bitmap when I read it both the ways.

Please suggest what I could do to get the face detection to work from sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I posted the question too quickly before doing a good search. Sorry for that.

I found the solution to the problem. It is basically the size of the image which creates the problem.
Follow this link. [Android Face detection only works with drawables not with images from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656144/android-face-detection-only-works-with-drawables-not-with-images-from-sd-card)